# Elegant way to render props regardless of their type

Tags: reactjs

Considering I have a component which accepts one prop, what would be the easiest and most elegant way for both of these to work:

`<MessageBlock message="Some message goes here" />`

and

```
<MessageBlock message={() => (
    <>
        Some message <strong>goes</strong> here
    </>
} />
```

What first comes to my mind is checking the prop type with `typeof` and rendering the prop according to that like this:

```
class MessageBlock extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { message: Message } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="message-block">
                {typeof Message === "function" ? (
                    <Message />
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {message}
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your component should be able to do.

If you want your component to be able to display anything inside of it, I would recommend using its `children` prop as a render function :

```js
const MessageBlock = props => (
  <div className={'add the stuff you want to wrap'}>
    {props.children()}
  </div>
)

const App = props => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <MessageBlock>
            {() => 
                <React.Fragment>
                    Some message <strong>goes</strong> here
                </React.Fragment>
            }
        </MessageBlock>
        <MessageBlock>
            {() => <p>Another message</p>}
        </MessageBlock>
    </React.Fragment>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

But if you want it to display a string and nothing else, use the `propTypes` with the first solution you proposed :

```
MessageBlock.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.string
};
```

If you want it to do both, you could put a `||` condition with it, if the message is defined. The message will be shown by default if it exists, and otherwise the children function will be executed :

```js
const MessageBlock = ({ children, message }) => (
  <div className={'add the stuff you want to wrap'}>
    {message || children()}
  </div>
)

/*MessageBlock.propTypes = { //Proptypes are undefined in SO snippets :(
    message: PropTypes.string
};*/

const App = props => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <MessageBlock>
            {() => 
                <React.Fragment>
                    Some message <strong>goes</strong> here
                </React.Fragment>
            }
        </MessageBlock>
        <MessageBlock message={'A string message'} />
    </React.Fragment>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```